# port forward on second router

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I am struggling to port forward my computer on a second router.

Here are my setup:

1. the main router **R1** (asus rt ac58u: 192.168.1.1;) connects to the modem; My WAN IP is static.
2. the second router **R2** (engenius 9850: 192.168.1.2) is connected via lan port between itself and the main router.
3. A computer **C1** (static ip: 192.168.1.10) that needs to be port forwarded. **C1** is connected via lan port to **R2**.

**R1** configurations:

1. Added port forwarding to **C1** with port range 80, local port 80.

**R2** configurations:

1. AP router mode
2. DHCP is disabled
3. NAT is disabled
4. No port forwarding is setup. Disabling of NAT also removes port forwarding.

I am able to browse my domain http://example.com within LAN. But it wouldn't work when I am out of my LAN.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the second router as a router, but just as a switch and access point. The port forwarding just needs to be set up on the first router. Many routers are unable to forward port 80 or require special setup to do it. That might be the issue here.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. On R2, there is no port forwarding. Port forwarding is setup only on R1. Earlier on, I connected my laptop (it has apache setup at 127.0.0.1) to R1 and setup port forwarding to this laptop @ port 80. I was able to browse my domain.

Comment: I finally got port forwarding to work. I factory reset both my routers, re-add the port forwarding on my main router, and restart my computer.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you Change the LAN and WAN Subnets of R2 to something like 192.168.2.0/24 (WAN) and 192.168.3.0/24(LAN) , and assign the computer C1 a static IP address in the new LAN range. Then , enable NAT on R2 , and forward port 80 to C1. Also, from R1 forward port 80 to R2 WAN IP address (192.168.2.1) .

Or , you could connect C1 to R1 , and forward from R1 to C1.